# visibility of menus based on usertypes

Tags: php, yii2

please help me

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
        ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],

          ['label' => 'ApplicationsForms', 'url' => ['/site/index'],
          'items' => [

            ['label' => 'Casual Leave', 'url' => ['casual-leaves/create']],
            ['label' => 'Mtech Leave', 'url' => ['mtech-leave/create']],
            ['label' => 'Phd Leave', 'url' => ['phd-leave/create']],
            ['label' => 'Duty Leave', 'url' => ['duty-leave/create']],

        ],'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest // && Yii::$app->user>identity->level == Usertable::level1,

     ],
        Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
            ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']] :
            [
                'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
            ],
    ],
]);
NavBar::end();
?>
```

this is my main.php code. i have more than two users .after login i have to redirect different pages. what can i do

Comment: maintain session and add usertype also .. if usertype = 1 then redirect to www.page1.com and if usertype = 2 then redirect to www.page2.com

Answer (score 0):

Redirects are handled in controller, not view:

```
if (Yii::$app->user->idendity->level = ...) {
    $this->redirect(['one-page']);
} elseif (Yii::$app->user->idendity->level = ...) {
    $this->redirect(['second-page']);
}

...
```